# How to handle a delegated event for child elements only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delegates, children

When delegating events using `.on` how do I target child elements:

I have tried: `childSelector =`

- `>*`
- `>:nth-child(n)`

But nothing is selected when I start with `>`.

```
$(selector).on(event, childSelector, handler);
```

Sometimes I want to target a direct child, sometimes I don't: (pseudo code)

```
var func = function(selector, subSelector) {
    $(selector).on("click", subSelector, function() {
        alert("my subSelector is clicked");
    });
}

func("#wrapper", "direct-child-selector");
func("#wrapper", ".some .other > .selector:first");
```

Thats why I'm asking for a selector and not a fix.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make any sense. A *child* is an element which is an immediate descendant of the element... e.g. `child.parentNode === parent`. An "*indirect child*" is merely a descendant; e.g. `descendant.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode(etc) === ancestor`. Because of how event bubbling works, if the delegated handler receives an event, you can *guarantee* the target of the event was a descendant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *could* check within the handler whether the element is a child of the element the event handler was delegated to;

```
$(selector).on("event", '*', function (e) {
    if (e.target.parentNode === e.delegateTarget) {
        // Woo!
    }
});
```

See [`e.delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/). Its worthy to note that `e.delegateTarget` was introduced in jQuery 1.7, so won't work on older versions.

**In regards to your second edit**, in it's current form the selectors are ambiguous; there's no way for you to, in code and in its current form, detect whether the selector passed is intended to be a child only selector. You can either introduce another parameter to indicate whether it's intended to be a child only selector, or add a `>` to the start of the selector (e.g.) and check for that;

```
var func = function(selector, subSelector, isChild) {
    $(selector).on("click", subSelector, function(e) {
        if (isChild && e.parentNode == e.delegateTarget || !isChild) {
             alert("my subSelector is clicked");
        }
    });
}

func("#wrapper", "direct-child-selector", true);
func("#wrapper", ".some .other > .selector:first" /* , `false` is optional */);
```

Or:

```
var func = function(selector, subSelector) {
    if (subSelector.charAt(0) === '>') {
        subSelector = selector + subSelector;
    }

    $(selector).on("click", subSelector, function(e) {
        alert("my subSelector is clicked");
    });
}

func("#wrapper", "> direct-child-selector");
func("#wrapper", ".some .other > .selector:first");
```

Comment: wow. didn't know about `delicateTarget`. But i still have a problem see edited question

Comment: ok thanks for your help. So there doesn't seem to a selector where you can assure to select the direct children and make room for selecting anything else with out a workaround.

Comment: I believe it needs to be `this.parentNode` rather than `e.parentNode`. Perhaps `e.target.parentNode` also works.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
$('#container').on('click', '> .children', function(){
...
})
```

Comment: Because you gave the children a specific class.

Answer (score 2):

One way to only delegate events triggered on direct children is to provide a full selector to `on()`, including the part that matches the parent element:

```
$(selector).on("event", selector + " > *", handler);
```

Comment: Is not `*` defined by W3C as something to "match all elements"?

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching

Comment: @LeeGee, yes, it is. Coupling it with a child selector (e.g. `"div > *"`) allows to match all the direct children of a given set of elements.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
childSelector = "*";
```

if it's supposed to match any child of the selector. It searches only in the scope of the selector.

Comment: That will match all *descendants*. An element is a child if it's an **immediate** descendant.